# Why is my 'Cucumber method' not finding information listed in data table?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, cucumber

Why is my 'Cucumber method' not finding information listed in data table?

All the other tables work, it cant seem to find the data within the [Text] (Parameter)' table.

```
    Then the user should be presented with the following prompt alert "<message"> 

Examples: 
    |              url                          |   username   |    password        |       message                 |
    |       http://www.example.com  |   user1      |    pass1           |   validation failed           |
    |       http://www.example.com  |   webdriver  |    webdriver123    |   validation succeeded        |



@Then("^the user should be presented with the following prompt alert \"([^\"]*)\">$")
public void the_user_should_be_presented_with_the_following_prompt_alert(String message) throws Throwable {
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    Assert.assertEquals(message, alert.getText());
}
```

As you can see im getting message returned instead of the actual data within the table:

```
 Then the user should be presented with the following prompt alert "<message"> # LoginSteps.the_user_should_be_presented_with_the_following_prompt_alert(String)
  org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[<message]> but was:<[validation failed]>
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
```

Comment: Your step has a typo: `"<message"> ` should be `"<message>"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is the typo in your step:

```
Then the user should be presented with the following prompt alert "<message">
```

Should be

```
Then the user should be presented with the following prompt alert "<message>"
```

You've got the `">` the wrong way round, so it's not parsing it as a data placeholder properly.